# how to Flatlist Automatically scroll to Top when changing screen

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using a normal vertical Flatlist to display data:

```
<FlatList style={stylesListagem.body}
            
            data={flatListItems}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={renderItem}                                
            
        />
```

Whenever the user enter in this screen I want that the scroll vertically go back to 0(start of the flatlist), because now if the user scroll to the last item for example , when he leave and back to this screen it saves the last position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete ! With a button event... not what I was expecting